# Using two columns to obtain count on another in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a simple question that I wasn't really sure how to search for (or title!). I apologize if this has been asked a million times. For the following table, how do I generate a report that will detail the number of companies that a person has worked for and how many people have also worked for that same number? So, for example, this table should return:

```
people, companiesperperson
   1,            1
   2,            2
   1,            3
```

for the following table called personalinfo:

```
id_number     first     last           company
   1             John      Doe            Intel
   2             John      Doe            Microsoft
   3             Phil      Jenkins        Amgen
   4             Phil      Jenkins        Bayer
   5             Phil      Jenkins        Sanofi
   6             Josh      Edwards        Walgreens
   7             Amy       Dill           URS
   8             Amy       Dill           ARCADIS
```

Let me know if this is still confusing and if I can further clarify what I am looking to do.

Thanks!

Comment: don't quite understand what you're asking for.

Comment: yes. its alittlebit confusing, show other example. which dataset you have and what u want to get

Comment: Let me try to explain it in a different way... I'm looking to obtain a count of how many companies that each person has worked for. It's clear that John Doe has worked for two companies (Intel and Microsoft) but I'm looking to be able to print a report of this information for use with a larger data set.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough estimate of the query but

```
SELECT count as companiesperperson, COUNT(first, last) as people FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(company) as count, first, last FROM personalinfo GROUP BY (first, last)) as a 
GROUP BY count
```

To explain the query first in the subquery we are asking for the names and count of companies after splitting up all the rows by names

Then in the outer query we split up all the rows by their count and ask how many unique names can be found in each group.

There may be a few syntax errors I've left straggling but the group by feature is really what's essential to understanding how to solve this question.